# How do I make pycharm recognize a string as a regex?

Tags: regex, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

How do I make PyCharm recognize a string as a regex?

Suppose that I have a list of regexes to match a string with. One way to do this is

```py
regexes = [re.compile(x) for x in [r'RESULTS?', r'DISCUSSION', r'REFERENCES?', r'ACKNOWLEDGE?MENTS?']]
```

But then PyCharm does not recognize the strings as regexes, nor does it provide code highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments), the following worked:

```py
regexes = [re.compile(x) for x in
           # language=RegExp
           [r'RESULTS?', r'DISCUSSION', r'REFERENCES?', r'ACKNOWLEDGE?MENTS?']]
```